# AngularJS: render HTML in directive controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I'm writing a directive for creating text from templates, but I cannot get to render my final result into HTML. This is the directive:

```
.directive('description', function($timeout){
  function descriptionCtrl(){
    var self = this;
    self.result = "";
    self.init = function(value) {
      console.log("template in directive",value);
      self.finalValue = "<div>HI <input type='text' id='hi' /></div>";
    };
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    controller : descriptionCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'dc',
    scope: {
      text: "="
    },
    replace: true,
    template: "<div id='template'>{{dc.finalValue}}</div>",
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch("text", function(value){
        if(value!==undefined){
          $timeout(ctrl.init(value),0);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The data comes from the controller and once the user has chosen between some options, hence the $watch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ng-bind-html` to bind html to the `div`

```
template: "<div id='template' ng-bind-html='dc.finalValue'></div>",
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I had to add as well the 'ngSanitize' to the module and the $sce.trustAsHtml(value) for having accepted the input.